# default JPA behavior for selecting non-existing entity

Tags: jpa

I'm writing some tests to make sure all the CRUD methods are working correctly. Every one of them are working fine, but it seems to be a little bit tricky to test the remove method.

In my test, I'm doing this:

```
// remove
a = dao.select(1); // previously inserted in the DB
dao.remove(a);
assertNull(dao.select(a.getId()));
```

And the DAO class (only select and remove):

```
@Override
 public AtividadeComercial select(int id) {
      return em.getReference(AtividadeComercial.class, id);
}

@Override
public void remove(AtividadeComercial e) {
    EntityTransaction t = em.getTransaction();
    boolean active = t.isActive();
    if(!active)
        t.begin();
    em.remove(em.getReference(e.getClass(), e.getId()));
    if(!active)
        t.commit();
}
```

But the test is always throwing a `javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException` on the line after `remove`. Is this the normal behavior or is something really wrong? Sorry if this seems to much obvious, but I couldn't find an answer to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getReference()` will never return null. Read its documentation:

> Get an instance, whose state may be lazily fetched. If the requested instance does not exist in the database, the EntityNotFoundException is thrown when the instance state is first accessed.

This method returns a proxy over an entity that is supposed to exist. It doesn't even make a database query to check if the entity exists: it assumes that it exissts. And if the proxy is initialized later, and the entity doesn't exist, then you'll get an EntityNotFoundException.

Comment: Thanks, I just found the same thing in [this article](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/retrieve). I replaced it with `find` and now it works fine.